# how to It.IsAny<T> in FakeItEasy?

Tags: moq, fakeiteasy

Does anyone know the equivalent of Moq `It.IsAny<T>` in FakeItEasy ?

I want to do assert that a method was called with an instance of a Type

```
v.Do(new Foo());
```

I tried:

```
A.CallTo(() => v.Do(A<Foo>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappened();
```

but this also accepts `v.Do()`;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right in the `A<Foo>.Ignored` (or `A<Foo>._`) is the equivalent of `It.IsAny<Foo>` in Moq.

<strike>It seems that you've hit a bug if what you say is actually correct. I'll get on it as soon as possible.</strike>

**EDIT**
I created the following integration test to reproduced the bug but the test passes so I'm not able to reproduce it, could you provide a code sample?

```
[Test]
public void Should_fail_assertion_when_overload_with_no_parameters_has_been_called_but_the_assertion_is_for_overload_with_parameters_but_ignoring_them()
{
    // Arrange
    var fake = A.Fake<ITypeWithOverloadedMethods>();

    // Act
    fake.Foo();

    // Assert
    Assert.Throws<ExpectationException>(() => A.CallTo(() => fake.Foo(A<int>._)).MustHaveHappened());
}

public interface ITypeWithOverloadedMethods
{
    void Foo();
    void Foo(int argument);
}
```